# How to produce value every 1 sec on rxjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, reactivex

If I already have an observable, then what operator should I use to make this
observable to produce value like, every 1 sec?

```
// this just an example, In my project, I can't control when the 
// observable will produce value. I can assume that it will produce
// value very fast.
const obs = from([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

The obs will emit the value 1,2,3... very quickly. But what if I want it to
emit the value every 1 sec? I mean, just make sure that obs emit value not too
quick?

I checked the document from reactivex, and can't find a operator to do so.
For example, delay, which just make the value production delay some time, but the relative time intervals between the values are preserved, and debounceTime
do produce value periodically but ignore values at that time window.

Can someone tell me how to make the observable produce value on period time
and not miss or ignore values?

Answer (score 8):

You could **zip** it with an **interval** observable like this:

```
import { zip, from, interval } from 'rxjs'

const obs = zip(
  from([1,2,3,4,5]),
  interval(1000),
  (val, i) => val // Just emit the value
)

obs.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

If you want the first value to emit immediately then you could use **timer** instead of **interval**:

```
import { zip, from, timer } from 'rxjs'

const obs = zip(
  from([1,2,3,4,5]),
  timer(0, 1000),
  (val, i) => val // Just emit the value
)

obs.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

You can also use a pipe if you prefer, like this:

```
import { from, interval } from 'rxjs'
import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators'

const obs = from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(
    zip(interval(1000), val => val)
  )

obs.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

### Update

The `zip` operator has been replaced with `zipWith`, which has no `resultSelector` parameter. `zip` Will be removed in v8.

Therefore, the example above that uses the `zip` operator can be updated as follows:

```
import { from, interval } from 'rxjs'
import { map, zipWith } from 'rxjs/operators'

const obs = from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(
    zipWith(interval(1000)),
    map(val => val[0])
  )

obs.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

Comment: 2021 UPDATE! The use of a function (resultSelector) inside the zip ( aka the (val) => val) is deprecated in rxjs. The behaviour can still be reproduced by taking the function out and placing it in a pipe(map()) like this: zip(from(myArray),interval(1000)).pipe(map((val)=>val[0]));
Note that the value return inside the map is 'val[0]' and not just 'val'.

Answer (score 2):

You can really use `delay` but you have to turn each delayed value into an Observable and then concat them into sequence with `concatMap`.

```
from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  concatMap(v => of(v).pipe(delay(1000))),
)
```

You could use `zip` but that will work correctly only with test data. `zip` emits only when all source Observables emit the same number of items. This means that if one Observable emits very fast, then slows down and then the second Observable start emitting fast it'll emit faster than with `1s` delays. This will happen even when `interval` and `zip` are combined because `zip` internally buffers all values so it might stack multiple emissions from `interval` and then reemit all of them at once if the second Observable emits very fast.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something of this sort

```js
var source = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 10)
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable
      .of(x)
      .delay(1000);
  })
 .timeInterval();
```

Comment: This uses outdated syntax.